# dbt: Env var required but not provided:

Tags: kubernetes, dbt

**Requirement**: To read environment variables values from Kubernetes to dbt profiles.yml file

**Issue**: profiles.yml unable to read Kubernetes secrets values

**Error** :

```
Parsing Error
Env var required but not provided: 'profilePassword'
```

I run dbt command in Airflow which is installed Kubernetes

Tried below

Created secrets in kubernetes

```
kubectl create secret generic profile-secret --from-literal=profileusername=ABC_SA --from-literal='password=abcd' -n airflow
```

updated in the yml file as

```
secret:
  - envName: profileUser
    secretName: "profile-secret"
    secretKey: "profileusername"     
  - envName: profilePassword
    secretName: "profile-secret"
    secretKey: "password"
```

In the dbt profiles.yml(Also tried without space)

```
abc_data:
  outputs:
    dev:
      account: abc
      user: DEV_SA
      password: "{{ env_var('profilePassword') }}"
      database: DEV
      role: DEV-ROLE
      schema: DEV_SCHEMA
      threads: 1
      type: snowflake
      warehouse: DEV_WH
  target: dev
```

When placed hardcoded password values, it runs fine
Or is there better way to read secret values

Comment: Did you update your Airflow Kubernetes Executor or Kubernetes Pod Operator configurations to inject the secrets as environment variables into your dbt-running container?

Comment: when i get into worker pod and run dbt debug it runs fine but not in airflow task :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved , issue was the python subprocesses was not reading the env variables

Comment: But how did you resolve that issue?

Comment: As I was using python Popen , the env doesn't automatically reads the vars , so i have to first read the envs from the os and then assign to Popen

Answer (score 0):

The error message  “Parsing Error Env var required but not provided: 'profilePassword' “ is indicating that some environment variables are not set properly .

As per this [dbt env variable official doc](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/env_var) , can you set the user name as user:
`"{{ env_var('DBT_USER') }}"` in your dbt profiles.yml  and have a try.

And also can you do the modifications as below in the secrets yml file because the secret key should match with env var password in dbt profile.yml . Seems you have given twice so try to do below modification and have a try.

```
secret:
  - envName: profileUser
    secretName: "profile-secret"
    secretKey: "profileusername"     
  - envName: profilePassword
```

You can also refer to this [dbt env var secret official doc](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/env_var#secrets) .

Comment: Did you mean username should also be created as env variable

Comment: @Kar : Yes, as mentioned in the doc

Comment: Should the password be encoded?

Comment: I am confused , when you mentioned  the secret key should match with env var password in dbt profile.yml .
secretkey is one kubernetes secrets created and the value envName  that is `profilePassword` is one should be in profile.yml right , also for user it is `profileUser`

Comment: I have added user: `"{{ env_var('DBT_USER') }}"       password: "{{ env_var('DBT_PASSWORD') }}"` 
[2023-03-31, 14:17:24 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} INFO -   Env var required but not provided: 'DBT_USER'

Comment: When i printenv in airflow below is the log 
`[2023-03-31, 14:17:11 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - DBT_USER=CICD_SA
[2023-03-31, 14:17:11 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES_SECRETS__DBT_USER=profile-secret=DBT_USER`

Comment: I got into the worker pod and ran `dbt debug` which is running fine but when i run in airflow task its failing `INFO - Env var required but not provided: 'DBT_USER' `